# Why is the expectation of a random vector defined to be the vector of the expectations of the coordinate random variables?

Tags: probability

Suppose I have a random vector $\textbf{X} = (X_1, X_2)^T$. Why should it be that the expected value of $\textbf{X}$ is defined to be $$E(\textbf{X}) = (E(X_1), E(X_2))^T?$$
After all, $X_1$ and $X_2$ may not be independent. It doesn't seem to make sense that we can compute the expected value of the vector by computing the expected values of the coordinates independently, as if each coordinate has no bearing on the other. What am I misunderstanding here?

For example, suppose I want to compute the expectation of a point randomly sampled on a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Can I really just compute the average values of the coordinates independently?

Answer (score 2):

Expected values are additive even for dependent random variables.
With $\mathbf X_1:=(X_1,0)^T$, $\mathbf X_2:=(0,X_2)^T$, You certainly agree that $E(\mathbf X_1)=(E(X_1),0)^T$ and $E(\mathbf X_2)=(0,E(X_2))^T$. Then
$$ E(\mathbf X)=E(\mathbf X_1+\mathbf X_2)=E(\mathbf X_1)+E(\mathbf X_2)=(E(X_1),E(X_2))^T$$

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting about how expectation is linear and how crucial that is. If it makes you feel better, you can write your vector $X = (X_1, 0) + (0, X_2)$, and use linearity of expectation to take the expectation of $X$.

Yup, you can find the average of the marginal distributions of each coordinate separately to find its center of mass.